# basic question about cauchy sequences and convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have open balls of the following form

$$ B_k = B( p_k, \epsilon_k ) $$

where $ \epsilon_k < \frac{1}{2^k} $ for all $k$. I want to show that $(p_k)$ is Cauchy:

my try:

$$ d(p_m,p_n) \leq d(p_m,0) + d(0,p_n) < \epsilon_m + \epsilon_n < \frac{1}{2^m} + \frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$$

hence $(p_k)$ is Cauchy. is this enough work?

Comment: What is $d(p_m)$?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the notation please? What does $B( p_k, \epsilon_k ) $ mean?

Comment: is an open ball with centre $p_k$ and radious $\epsilon_k$

Comment: Pardon my idiocy.. But is there some nesting condition for the $B_k$s? Otherwise the sequence $(p_k)$ need not be Cauchy. Consider $\Bbb R$ and let $p_k = k \in \Bbb N$. Under the usual metric simply because the $\epsilon_k$s are constrained does not imply the sequence $(p_k)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Don't you need something more?  Like perhaps $0 \in B_k$ for every $k$?  Otherwise, this need not be true, as the example given by @Ishfaaq shows.

Comment: @MathcanbeFun It may be worth noting that the statement is actually true if we assume $B_k \cap B_{k+1} \neq \emptyset$ for every $k\geq 1$.  However, the question, as written, is false without providing further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer seems right, except for the $<$ in the thired inequality. Perhaps you should justify the steps - model your answer similar to the below - **assuming $B_k$ is centered at the origin**:

> To show that $(p_k)$ is Cauchy, we need to show that $d(p_m,p_n)\to0$. By the triangle inequality, $d(p_m,p_n)\leq d(p_m,0)+d(0,p_n)$. It then follows that $d(p_m,0)+d(0,p_n)=\epsilon_m+\epsilon_n$. Since $\epsilon_m+\epsilon_n<\dfrac{1}{2^m}+\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, which goes to $0$, we see that $d(p_m,p_n)\to0$, showing that $(p_k)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Are you assuming that $0$ is in each ball, just as OP is?  Without further information, we don't have that.

Comment: @NicholasStull I am - I didn't realize I was doing that. Hence, I edited my answer.

Comment: If every $B_k$ is centered at the origin, then of course $(p_k)$ is Cauchy.  It's the constant sequence $(0)$.  This is why I am a bit skeptical about this question, as it is stated.  The statement is actually still true if $0 \in B_k$, for every $k$, with the proof given above, and in this case, $p_k \to 0$.

Comment: @NicholasStull Yes, I understand that.

Comment: I know you understand that.  I'm pointing this out in the hope that OP will edit/clarify the question to address this issue...

Comment: @NicholasStull If not, then is it right to close the question?